# Setting Azure Webjob Time Zones

Tags: c#, azure, datetime, console-application, azure-webjobs

I have a C# console App job set as a Azure WebJob. This honors UTC time zone for the trigger and runtime. I have updated the Server Application Config to "Eastern Standard Time" as in the picture.

[image]

The Webjob still does not honor the EST time zone. I can see there is a disconnect between the Web App server and the Webjob service as hosts. I wanted to ask if there is a non-code change way to fix this, so that **DateTime.Now = EST and Not UTC**. I can fix it in the code but try to find a way to fix this in a non-coding way.

**NOTE:** OS is Windows

Comment: Where you are checking for the update in the timezone?

Comment: is this a linux app service plan?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio  This is for Windows. I have updated the question

Comment: @Harshitha This is for Windows. I have updated the question

Comment: from the kudu console, you could check the time: `time` should give you back the current local time

Comment: @Thomas Unfortunately that does not help me, I have the code using DateTime.Now expression in several places that need the EST times. I can add additional code to fix the gap. that would be very hacky. I would like to set the Server time to be set to EST instead. But it seems the Webjobs do not honor the server set timezone.

Comment: `I have the code using DateTime.Now expression in several places that need the EST times.` Could you please share the code once.

Comment: @Harshitha it is as simple as DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

Comment: What I mean is checking on the kudu console is the app service is set with the right timezone: bug in app service or issue in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `Azure App service` displays `UTC`.

Thanks @Thomas for the Comment.

We can see the timezone in `Debug Console` =>`Powershell` with `timezone`.

[image]

- In `Visual Studio`, I have created a sample `Console App`.

***My `Program.cs`:***

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("The current time is: " + dt.ToString());
```

- Build and run the Application.
- Create a new `Azure App Service` in Azure Portal and create a new Web Job.
- Zip the files into a new folder from your local folder `****\bin\Debug\net6.0`.

[image]

- Upload the newly zipped folder while creating web job in portal.

[image]

- Now, Check the running job Logs.
  [image]

[image]

I have set the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE`  values to `Eastern Standard Time` same as you have shown.

[image]

- Now check the updated time zone in KUDU Console, `Debug Console` =>`Powershell` with `timezone`.

[image]

- Now check the same in the running job Logs.
  [image]

Comment: The zip file showed in the image was created at 9:55 am - what time  zone is that datetime? I appreciate your efforts. Was the webjob created and ran just after the zip file was created?

Comment: Zip is my local time.IST

Comment: Yes,I have created web job within the same hour after creating the zip file.My zip file is IST.First screen shot is UTC and last is as per your requirement EST.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort to help me figure this out. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: One observation that does not make a difference in my case, the jobs cron expressions still honor UTC and if you see the Log times on the left of the log (red box on the last image) are in UTC.

Comment: Yes..that is the timezone of the UTC.Even I observed that the timezone is changing only in the logs of Webjob.